# Comparing & sorting array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays. They have different attributes.

```
array1 = [{name: "apple", quantity: 2}, {name: "grape", quantity: 10}, {name: "pear", quantity: 3}]
array2 = [{name: "grape", freshness: 9}, {name: "apple", freshness: 7}, {name: "pear", freshness: 10}]
```

I would like to sort `array1` based on `array2`'s order, by name. The result would be:

```
array1 = [{name: "grape", quantity: 10}, {name: "apple", quantity: 2}, {name: "pear", quantity: 3}]
```

Comment: No. I can't. It already has an answer.

Comment: Are the names unique and identical in both arrays?

Comment: A quick search on ["\[ruby\] sort array based on another array"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+sort+array+based+on+another+array) will find other versions of this question.

Comment: @muistooshort I've reopened the question - I think comparing / sorting by identical attributes is a special case and there might be more specific answers to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it given your current data structure.

```
array1 = array1.sort_by { |x| array2.find_index { |y| y[:name] == x[:name] } }
```

However, note that `find_index` takes O(n) time. This can be improved by using a different model for your data or by doing some preprocessing (e.g., see Stefan's answer).

Answer (score 7):

You could build a `name => index` hash:

```
h = array2.map { |e| e[:name] }.each_with_index.to_h
#=> {"grape"=>0, "apple"=>1, "pear"=>2}
```

And sort by that hash:

```
array1.sort_by { |e| h[e[:name]] }
#=> [{:name=>"grape", :quantity=>10}, {:name=>"apple", :quantity=>2}, {:name=>"pear", :quantity=>3}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
h = array1.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[e[:name]] = e}
array1 = array2.map{|e| h[e[:name]]}
```

Comment: Sorting without using `sort`, it took me a while to understand what's going on :-)

Comment: @Stefan I considered modifying `array1` into an appropriate structure. You considered modifying `array2`. From the point of view that the question is to reorder `array1`, your answer may make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
array2.map { |h2| array1.detect { |h1| h1[:name] == h2[:name] } }
```

---

```
require 'benchmark'

@array1 = [{name: "apple", quantity: 2}, {name: "grape", quantity: 10}, {name: "pear", quantity: 3}]
@array2 = [{name: "grape", freshness: 9}, {name: "apple", freshness: 7}, {name: "pear", freshness: 10}]

n = 500_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report {n.times { @array2.map { |h2| @array1.detect { |h1| h1[:name] == h2[:name] } } } }
  x.report {n.times { @array1.sort_by { |x| @array2.find_index { |y| y[:name] == x[:name] } } } }
  x.report {n.times { h = @array1.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[e[:name]] = e} ; @array1 = @array2.map{|e| h[e[:name]] } } }
  x.report {n.times { h = @array2.map { |e| e[:name] }.each_with_index.to_h ; @array1.sort_by { |e| h[e[:name]] } }}
  x.report {n.times { @array1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] = g }.values_at(*@array2.map { |g| g[:name] }) }}
end

    user     system      total        real
0.960000   0.000000   0.960000 (  1.064233)
1.040000   0.020000   1.060000 (  1.291731)
0.850000   0.000000   0.850000 (  1.064816)
1.680000   0.000000   1.680000 (  2.131733)
0.840000   0.000000   0.840000 (  1.057844)
```

For large array, on the other hand, @sawa and @Stefan gave equally good results (added a Cary's solution):

```
100.times { |i| @array1 << {name:i}; @array2 << {name:i} }
@array1.shuffle!
@array2.shuffle!

    user     system      total        real
5.970000   0.000000   5.970000 (  6.154653)
4.980000   0.010000   4.990000 (  5.111118)
0.450000   0.010000   0.460000 (  0.469722)
0.640000   0.010000   0.650000 (  0.655721)
0.480000   0.010000   0.490000 (  0.490590)
```

Comment: Try to benchmark larger arrays: `100.times { |i| @array1 << {name:i}; @array2 << {name:i} }`

Comment: Can you add the one I just posted? It appears relatively fast for larger arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yours appears to be a winner amongst Sawa's: it is in fastest group for both small and huge arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] = g }.
  values_at(*array2.map { |g| g[:name] })
  #=> [{:name=>"grape", :quantity=>10}, {:name=>"apple", :quantity=>2},
  #    {:name=>"pear", :quantity=>3}]
```